# Microsoft Xaml Element Equivalent of Xamarin Xaml "ContentView"

Tags: xaml, xamarin, win-universal-app

I have recently started a Xamarin Forms project specifically for the Universal Windows Platform.  In attempt to add some global styles for the application, I have come across an element I don't know the uwp equivalent syntax for: Xamarin `ContentView`.

(ie. I know that Xamarin `Label` = UWP`TextBlock`, Xamarin `HorizontalOptions` = UWP`HorizontalAlignment`)

Xamarin:

```
<Style x:Key="errorContainer" TargetType="ContentView">        
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Fill"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15"/>
</Style>
```

UWP:

```
<Style x:Key="errorContainer" TargetType="?????????">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15"/>
</Style>
```

tldr; Xamarin `ContentView` = UWP `??????`

Thanks for the help

Comment: Would it be content presenter? Is that a thing in Universal Apps? It's a WPF control.

Answer (score 0):

`ContentControl` (and it's derived types like `Border`) should fit your need.

(Because it has a `ContentTemplate` Property, as Xamarin.Forms' `ContentView` derives from `TemplatedView`.)